# Кто сможет подсказать, как сделать отображение в мобильной версии сайта вид плагина как на ПК?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, elementor

Плагин WP Tabs Pro в полной версии сайта выглядит нормально, а в мобильной расположение вкладок меняется на расположение как в аккордеоне.Как сделать, чтобы секция элементор на мобильной версии оставалась как на ПК, или сам плагин не менял вид

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Сайт на WP elementor

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку